# Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException

Tags: sqlite

> Fatal Exception:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to
>   open database file (code 2062)

#

> Error Code : 2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE) Caused By : Application has
>   opened two many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one
>   process is 1024 in default.   (unable to open database file (code
>   2062))

#

```
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:930)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
   at com.example.agc_linux.intoo.chatdata.FriendDB.getFriendDataBasedOnId(FriendDB.java:74)
   at com.example.agc_linux.intoo.chatdata.FriendDB.addFriend(FriendDB.java:39)
   at com.example.agc_linux.intoo.fragment.FriendsFragment$7.onDataChange(FriendsFragment.java:649)
   at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeex.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegs.zzbwg(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegy.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: format error code

Comment: You need to audit your code and ensure that you are closing the files that you open. You can not just leave it to the GC.

Comment: Make sure you close cursors when done with them.